# OmniGraffle Objeck Trim

Tags: macos, omnigraffle

Is there an AutoCAD like Trim Function in OmniGraffle where I can cut of parts of Lines and Objects between Objects?

In the Example Picture I would like to trim the red parts of the line, crossing both circles. With the result, having 3 new individual lines.

In AutoCAD I would draw both circles and the line and with trim I could set both circles as borders and delete lines within.

[image: trim red parts ot the line]